# Jsp - Getting all parameters starting with characters

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

If I have the following query:

```
http://example.com/mywebapp/mypage.jsp?names=John&names=Steve
```

How do I extract both names from the get parameter of 'names'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ServletRequest#getParameterValues(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29)

e.g.

```
String[] names = request.getParameterValues("names");
```